# Mutiple logs in single config file to elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to send logs from different location to elasticsearch using logstash conf file.

```
input {           
    file
    {
path => "C:/Users/611166850/Desktop/logstash-5.0.2/logstash-5.0.2/logs/logs/ce.log" 
type => "CE"
start_position => "beginning" 
 }
file
{
path => "C:/Users/611166850/Desktop/logstash-5.0.2/logstash-5.0.2/logs/logs/spovp.log" 
type => "SP"
start_position => "beginning" 
 } 
file
{
path => "C:/Users/611166850/Desktop/logstash-5.0.2/logstash-5.0.2/logs/logs/ovpportal_log" 
type => "OVP"
start_position => "beginning" 
 } 

}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    action => "index"
    hosts => "localhost:9200"
    index => "multiple"
codec => json 
workers => 1
  }
}
```

This is the config file I use, but Kibana is not recognising this index. Can someone help with this

Thanks in advance ,Rashmi

Answer (score 0):

Check logstash's log file for errors.(maybe you'r config file is not correct)
Also search ES directly for preferred index, maybe problem is not Kibana, and you don't have any index with this name.

Answer (score 0):

try starting logstash in debug mode to see if there are any logs in it. 
you can also try to get the logstash out put to a file on local system rather than directly sending it to the elasticsearch. uncomment block as per your requirement

```
# block-1
#  if "_grokparsefailure" not in [tags] {
#   stdout {
#    codec => rubydebug { metadata => true }
#   }
#  }
# block-2
#  if "_grokparsefailure" not in [tags] {
#    file {
#    path => "/tmp/out-try1.logstash"
#    }
# }
```

so by any of these methods you can get the output to console or to a file. comment _grokparsefailure part in case you don't see any output in file.

Note: in kibana default indices have @timestamp in their fields so check 
1. if kibana is able to recognize the index if you unckeck the checkbox on page where you create new index
2. if your logs are properly parsed. if not you need to work out with grok filters with pattern matching your logs or create grok filters

all elasticsearch indices are visible on http://elasticsearch-ip:9200/_cat/indices?v (your elasticsearch ip) so try that too. share what you find